# XSLT - Merge two files with same node value

Tags: loops, xslt, merge

I have two xml files with identical values that I want to merge. I would like to merge the content of the second file into the first one based on the value of SystemId and Title.

the first file:

```xml
<Package>
      <Descriptive>
         <Unit id="Id_1502037">
            <Content>
               <Description>Description 1</Description>
               <SystemId>1502037</SystemId>
            </Content>
            <Unit id="Id_Comp_1502037">
               <Content>
                  <Description>Description 1.1</Description>
               </Content>
            </Unit>
         </Unit>
         <Unit id="Id_1502043">
            <Content>
               <Description>Description 2</Description><SystemId>1502043</SystemId>
            </Content>
            <Unit id="Id_Comp_1502043">
               <Content>
                  <Description>Description 2.1</Description>
               </Content>
            </Unit>
         </Unit>
      </Descriptive>
   </Package>
```

And second file :

```xml
<Package>
    <Descriptive>
      <Unit id="ID10">
        <Content>
          <Description>Description 1.2</Description>
          <Title>1502037</Title>
        </Content>
      </Unit>
      <Unit id="ID20">
        <Content>
          <Description>Description 2.2</Description>
          <Title>1502043</Title>
        </Content>
      </Unit>
    </Descriptive>
  </Package>
```

The desired result :

```xml
<Package>
      <Descriptive>
         <Content>
            <Description>Description 1</Description>
            <SystemId>1502037</SystemId>
         </Content>
         <Unit id="Id_Comp_1502037">
            <Content>
               <Description>Description 1.1</Description>
            </Content>
         </Unit>
         <Unit id="ID10">
            <Content>
               <Description>Description 1.2</Description>
               <Title>1502037</Title>
            </Content>
         </Unit>
         <Content>
            <Description>Description 2</Description>
            <SystemId>1502043</SystemId>
         </Content>
         <Unit id="Id_Comp_1502043">
            <Content>
               <Description>Description 2.1</Description>
            </Content>
         </Unit>
         <Unit id="ID20">
            <Content>
               <Description>Description 2.2</Description>
               <Title>1502043</Title>
            </Content>
         </Unit>
      </Descriptive>
   </Package>
```

I wrote the following XSLT ($ressource = file2.xml):

```xml
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="Descriptive">
        <xsl:element name="Descriptive">
            <xsl:for-each select="Unit">
                <xsl:variable name="ids" select="Content/SystemId"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$ressource/Package/Descriptive/Unit/Content/Title[. = $ids]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$ressource/Package/Descriptive/Unit"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

It's almost right but the result repeats all the nodes of the second file. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Please always say which XSLT version you are using - it usually affects the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="$ressource/Package/Descriptive/Unit/Content/Title[. = $ids]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$ressource/Package/Descriptive/Unit"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

That's saying "for each Unit, copy all the units". You just want to copy all the units that match the condition, which is

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$ressource/Package/Descriptive/Unit[Content/Title=$ids]"/>
```

(Not tested - there might be other errors as well).